# Ivy mis-resolve resources

Tags: gwt, ivy

I've a simple `ivy.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency org="javax.validation" name="validation-api" rev="1.0.0.GA" conf="compile->master,sources"/>
</dependencies>
```

where `compile` is my configuration name, and `master,sources` are the mapped Maven types.
This is resolved correctly and give me these files:

```
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar
```

Now, i've to add this dependency:

```
<dependency org="com.google.gwt" name="gwt-user" rev="2.8.1" conf="compile->default"/>
```

which has `validation-api` as its dependecy, the same i specified at the top.

Ivy resolves this giving me these files:

```
gwt-user-2.8.1.jar
<its dependecies>
validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar
```

but this time the file `validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar` is not retrieved.
Why?
I think this file is not in conflict... what should i do to have `gwt-user` and the `validation-api` jars (**binary and source**)?

Answer (score 0):

This happens mainly due to the way configurations are declared in the ivy xmls. If you are dealing with a Maven artifact, it's very common that the ivy xml generated from the Maven artifact uses a different conf tag for the dependency. You are resolving the "default" conf of gwt-user. Normally, "default" extends "master, runtime". So, if validation-api-1.0.0.GA was declared under "master" or "runtime" conf in gwt-user's ivy.xml, it would have got resolved.

In order to give more accurate answer, I need the  part of your ivy.xml as well as the ivy.xml of gwt-user